# SSAS Tabular - Power Query Editor stuck at "Operation in progress" - "identifying schemas"

Tags: ssas, powerquery, ssas-tabular

In Visual Studio, with an SSAS Tabular model open, in the Power Query Editor window, when I make a change to a large partition (1 million+ rows) that sources its data from an Azure SQL Database, the edit and preview happens quickly in the Power Query Editor window itself.  However, when I click "Close & Update" or "Close & Update Without Processing" this message appears for a very long time ("Operation in progress" - "identifying schemas"):

[image: "Operation in progress" - "identifying schemas"]

At the same time, Task Manager shows Visual Studio downloading at several Mbps the entire time, so I am assuming that Visual Studio is attempting to download the full contents of the table.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?  I was thinking that "Close & Update Without Processing" would prevent this behavior but it does not.

My current workaround is:

1. Rename the Azure SQL Database table.
2. Create a new empty Azure SQL Database table with the same name and fields as the original table.
3. Perform the "Close & Update" letting it use this empty table as a source so it completes instantly.
4. Delete the new empty Azure SQL Database table.
5. Rename the Azure SQL Database table back to what it was previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The work around that I have found is to use a parameter to limit the number or rows being used for development.  An example of how to set this up is here:
https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2018/02/26/filtering-data-loaded-into-a-workspace-database-in-analysis-services-tabular-2017-and-azure-analysis-services/